# Inline div elements

Tags: html, inline

I'm trying to put div elements right next to each other.  The problem is, even if there is enough room for the two elements to be on the same line, the new div moves itself to the next line, I need the other div only to go to the next line if there isn't enough room.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: you should use `span` elements if you need generic inline elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the CSS display style to `display:inline-block;`.

This allows the element to keep it's block-like functionality, while also allowing it to be displayed inline. It's a half-way house between the two.

(But note that there are some compatibility issues with older versions of IE)

Comment: See http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block for a detailed comparison, as well as a discussion of the compatibility issues with IE 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 5):

Divs are block level elements, so by default they will always occupy an entire line. The way to change this is to float the divs:

```
<div style="float: left"></div>
```

Comment: And to start a next inline element on a new line, add style="clear: both" to that element.

Comment: OP said: " I need the other div only to go to the next line if there isn't enough room" so in this case, no clearing should be used. That's good advice for other situations, though.

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity; I meant an element, other than the div's in question. Probably OP has more markup beyond those. ;)

Comment: Wouldn't inline-block be a better solution? Floats tend to be pretty messy; clearing the containers, preventing issues with other floats, making sure text wraps around them properly...

Comment: Here is a detailed comparison of the two methods: http://www.ternstyle.us/blog/float-vs-inline-block There are pros and cons for each. For me, the most compelling argument is that IE 7 and earlier do not deal with inline-block appropriately. I often find it easier to deal with the consequences of floating than to create alternate styles for IE 7 and earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Use `float`'s and `margin`'s; that way when there's no space you can just put `overflow:hidden` to the `container` hide the rest of the `div` instead of making it go to the next line.

### CSS

```
.container {
  width:500px;
  background:#DADADA;
  overflow:hidden; /* also used as a clearfix */
}

.content {
  float:left;
  background:green;
  width:350px;
}
.sidebar {
  width:155px; /* Intentionaly has more width */ 
  margin-left:350px; /* Width of the content */
  background:lime;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

In this demo you can see: floats, margin+floats, display:inline-block.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kuroir/UupbG/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `float` CSS rule. Just use some class or identifier and set `float` to `left` or `right`.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you have a fixed width to the `div`s