# Placing 3 div's Side by Side

Tags: html, css

I want to place 3 divs side by side using CSS. I have gone through many posts on SO, but not getting the thing working for my project.

```
#quotescointainer{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#quotesleft{
    float:left; 
    width: 33%;
    background-color: white;
}
#quotescenter{ 
    background-color:white;
    width: 33%;
}
#quotesright{
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
}
```

The above does not place the div's in the correct place. I cannot seem to figure out the mistake I am making.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could `float: left` *all* the inner `div`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/W8dyy/

You should fix the spelling of `quotescointainer` to `quotescontainer`.

```
#quotescointainer{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow: hidden; /* contain floated elements */
    background: #ccc
}
#quotesleft {
    float: left; 
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
#quotescenter { 
    float: left;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 33%;
}
#quotesright{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Comment: +1 Good but please don't copy `width:33%` three times and `background-color:#bbb`.

Comment: @Midas: That's a fair point, but I was trying to keep it simple for the OP. I'd probably do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/W8dyy/1/

Comment: @Midas: I was not going use width 3 times. Presently just in beta phase of development. So getting some prototypes in.

Comment: @DalexL: The OP wasn't sure which to pick :) See: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6208214/timeline I felt that I should post an answer that was using `float`s, like the OP's code.

Comment: @thirtydot LOL!  That is awesome!  Well, the OP chooses :)

Comment: float:left breaks layout outside of the container. In practice it is not usable. The only way to position things in html with predictable result are tables.

Comment: it has 1% free space on the right, if the quotescointainer width is to large, e.g 1% of 960px free space is 9px.

Comment: @SeSong: True, you can use `width: 33.33%` to fix it, or use a `display: table` based approach instead.

Answer (score 1):

I recently asked this exact same question.

Here is a link:

[Inline div elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072573/inline-div-elements)

Here is my accepted answer:

> Set the CSS display style to
>   display:inline-block;.
>
> This allows the element to keep it's
>   block-like functionality, while also
>   allowing it to be displayed inline.
>   It's a half-way house between the two.
>
> (But note that there are some
>   compatibility issues with older
>   versions of IE)

Answer (score 1):

With the advent of CSS grids, this can be better achieved it rather than using `display: inline` and `float`.

https://jsfiddle.net/dxec62vk/

Also there is good browser support for `grid` now: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid